# Why can't I do 1.toString() but I can do var a = 1; a.toString()

Tags: javascript, c#

When I do

```
1.toSting()
```

I get an error, but

```
// javascript
var a = 1; 

// or c#
int a = 1
a.toString()
```

works. Why is it that when a number gets assigned to a variable, it get some special functions?

Comment: No error in C# for me, if you do `1.ToString();`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.` is interpreted as you want a decimal/floating-point literal, not invoking a member.

You can do this in JavaScript

```
// Option 1
(1).toString();
// Option 2
1.0.toString();
// Option 3
1..toString();
```

In C#, it appears your only option is `(1).ToString()`, but the lexer might be smart enough not to need them.

Comment: Yep, this is a lexer "issue." For example you COULD do this: (1).toString()

Comment: It appears that `1..toString()` also works, at least in Chrome's console.